# Upload platform specific python wheels to pypi from github actions

Tags: python, github-actions, pypi, python-manylinux

My project has a small platform specific pre-compiled binary (with no extension) that it depends on.

I am able to use a combination of package_data and a post_install script to automate building and pushing the wheels to pypi for macos and windows.

However I am unable to do the same with linux as pypi requires linux wheels to use manylinux. I tried using cibuild but since my package doesn't actually contain anything other than pure python and this pre-compiled binary it fails. I don't see any github actions for many linux, does anyone know how to do this?

This is my github actions for reference:

```
name: Build and Publish Linux Wheel

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  build_wheels:
    name: Build wheels on Ubuntu
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel

      - name: Build wheel
        run: |
          python setup.py bdist_wheel
        env:
          PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1

      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: wheels
          path: dist/*.whl

  upload_wheels:
    needs: build_wheels
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true || github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    steps:
      - name: Download wheels
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: wheels
          path: dist/

      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8

      - name: Install twine
        run: python -m pip install twine

      - name: Publish Linux wheels to Test PyPI
        run: |
          twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*.whl
        env:
          TWINE_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.PYPI_USERNAME }}
          TWINE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PYPI_PASSWORD }}
```

Comment: IIUC, https://github.com/pypa/manylinux provides docker images that you can use with [`jobs.<job_id>.container`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer).